# LTR to RTL jQuery Collapsibles block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking to know how to convert from LTR to RTL the

http://www.beladitvnews.com/news/en-iraqi-mofa-ambassadors to RTL .

Code been used for to create this was :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Collapsible Blocks</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
      <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Plus as you can see first element because of alot of text it's not showing even when you click on expand.

Please advise 
Thank you
Kind regards

Comment: Did you try anything? `direction:rtl` ? Any googling? Did you read stuff like http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/ ?

Comment: Hi , thank you for respond, i could rtl the content but not the plus sign and label

Comment: Ha, that's an important information you didn't mention in your original question. So you tried? What exactly did you try? (post CSS, etc.) The "plus" sign is an `:after` pseudo-element, I guess it can be moved to the right using `.ui-btn-icon-left:after{ float:right }`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, i did place your code '.ui-btn-icon-left:after{ float:right } ' @JeremyThille but the plus sign just disappeared. when i place 'direction:rtl' but it didn't work it just show the content in RTL mode but not the Label

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the block with the "+" sign you're trying to reverse. I have added 4 lines and it did the trick. See below, if you remove/comment my 4 lines, the "+" goes back to the left :

```css
div{
    background : lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
}

a.ui-icon-plus{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    
    padding-left: 40px;    /* this is the original value */
    padding-right: 16px;   /* this is the original value */
    
    padding-left: 16px;  /* Added this to overwrite */
    padding-right: 40px; /* Added this to overwrite */
   
}

a.ui-icon-plus:after{

    content: "";
    left: 9px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23FFF%22%20points%3D%2214%2C5%209%2C5%209%2C0%205%2C0%205%2C5%200%2C5%200%2C9%205%2C9%205%2C14%209%2C14%209%2C9%2014%2C9%20%22%2F%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    
    left: auto;     /* Added this to overwrite */
    right: 0;       /* Added this to overwrite */

}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a href="#" class="ui-icon-plus">
            Dhiaa Hadi Mahmoud AlDabas -----&gt;
            <br>
            Iraq's Ambassador to the republic of Iraq in Cairo and The Representative of Iraq to the Arab Leaque
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond and your code, it worked perfectly fine except that the minus sign appear on left side after expanding any block, and text remains on the left side.

Comment: Well, it's the same. The minus sign is a `.ui-icon-minus` with an `:after`, just apply the same code on it.